# Chrome - reload imported script module (HMR like)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to reload already loaded javascript module (native) without page reload?

Sample to illustrate the case:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <button onclick="reload()">reload</button>
 </body>
</html>

function reload() {
   import('sample.js').then(() => console.log(loaded))
}
```

I would like to "re import" the script "on demand". I know that import will download file only once per file path. Is there any other way to download and execute updated script than giving it some kind of timestamp?

```
 import('sample.js?' + random)
```

Edit: Also if there are any imports inside sample.js i would like to reload them also.

IT Man

Comment: DevTools does it automatically when a workspace is added (in Sources panel) and devtools itself is open.

Comment: @wOxxOm It seems not to work as I expected. File is updated in workspace/editor but import seems to relay on initialy load code...
Referring to sample case, when button clicked and import executed it will check whether script was already downloaded, and will skip to reload modified one. Instead control goes to .then part immediately.

Comment: The imported file should probably be opened in devtools too.

Comment: @wOxxOm no difference, I can even change file content inside devtools editor but still, import('sample.js') stucks on initially loaded version.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm examining case when sample.js has inner import from file sample2.js and I'm changing sample2.js.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is:

```js
const url = 'sample.js?now=' + Date.now();
import(url).then(() => console.log(loaded))
```

However, that only works for `sample.js`. The "inner" imports are still stuck on the oldest version. :(

Comment: Looks like some additional engine is required to manage module files content caches and generate some checksums for additional parameter you have suggested. I believe such solution webpack or vite is using.

Comment: I have no time to test RN, but can you test https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims/ ? I think it should work without any bundler.